# Lots of Locked Queries with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First off, I'm a total noob when it comes to servers and MySQL. So, with answers, if at all possible, could you please explain a little bit? We lost our main web developer not long ago and I only know some HTML and PHP coding, so I'm at a loss when it comes to this stuff.

Currently, our server is constantly crashing. I mean, 10-12 times a day our sites are all down. I've contacted our host, and they think they identified the issue, but said it's an issue for our web developer to look into. So, basically, they won't help us.

What they said is, "There is a problem with MySQL, as in there are a lot of locked queries in your database that are killing the server." They then listed the queries. Here is the list they provided:

```
+-----+---------------+-----------+----------------------+---------+------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| Id | User | Host | db | Command | Time | State | Info |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| 296 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1978 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 297 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1978 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 302 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1983 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 304 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1979 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 308 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1984 | Sending data | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 311 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1984 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 313 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1979 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 317 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1978 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 319 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1979 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 322 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1978 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 327 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1978 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 329 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1978 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 332 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1978 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 334 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1984 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 336 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1978 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 342 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1978 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 343 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1978 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 344 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1983 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 348 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1983 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 350 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1979 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 356 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1978 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 360 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1979 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 361 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1983 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_posts.I |
| 365 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1945 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 366 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1884 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 368 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1909 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 373 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1824 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 374 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1813 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 376 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1641 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 392 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1436 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 394 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1411 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 396 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1411 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 399 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1383 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 403 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1335 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 406 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1336 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 411 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1281 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 415 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1062 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 416 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1038 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 418 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1038 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 419 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 1018 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 420 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 989 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 421 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 989 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 422 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 918 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 426 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 824 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 427 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 691 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 431 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 631 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 432 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 631 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 435 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 542 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 437 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 542 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 441 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 478 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 442 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 414 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 445 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 352 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT
wp_comment |
| 446 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 302 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 447 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 309 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT
wp_comment |
| 449 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 174 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 450 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 174 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 451 | wp_1265455606 | localhost | wordpress_1265455606 | Query | 73 | Locked | insert into cs365_change (id,table_id,trigger_time,trigger_day,expression,hashmd5)
SELECT

wp_comment |
| 453 | root | localhost | | Query | 1 | | show processlist
```

Is this something I should fix? This is a huge issue, because we have a web store that is currently always down. Any help, direction pointing, etc., would majorly, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are using `MyISAM` tables. `MyISAM` uses table level locking so whenever you do an insert the entire table is locked. Switching to `InnoDB` will allow the use of row level locking which should prevent contention on inserts.

This can be done by doing `ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE=InnoDB;` for each table.

See [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help Jim! That worked beautifully. Have a nice day!